# Android: How to change edittext cursor drop

Tags: android, android-edittext

On Android 4.x.x the color of cursor drop in EditText is not correct (is white and must be normally red like Android 5):

[image]

On Android 5 and 6 the color is correct (same like red cursor).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Set following property

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
```

then cursor will take whatever color you will set to text. #000000 for black color

```
android:textColor="#000000"
```